# Why was Dink changed from being a Christian in the 1991 version of Ender's Game?

Tags: enders-game, orson-scott-card

Original 1985 text:

> "That's right, we never cry. Christ, I never thought of that. Nobody ever cries.

Revised 1991 text:

> "That's right, we never cry. I never thought of that. Nobody ever cries.

Why was this changed?

Comment: "Christ" in this context is just being used a type of mild curse, like "god damn"--both expressions are reasonably common in English-speaking countries with a Christian history, even among those who aren't themselves Christian, or religious believers of any kind. Maybe Cloud removed it because he's a conservative Christian and he wanted to make the book "safe" for other conservative Christians to read, so he removed this mildly "blasphemous" use of "Christ".

Comment: @Hypnosifl Who is Cloud?

Comment: @user14111 - just a mental slip on my part, I think my brain was mixing up Ender's Game author Orson Scott Card with the cartoonist [Scott McCloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_McCloud), so I remembered the author's name incorrectly as "Orson Scott Cloud".

Comment: If anything, using *"Christ"* as a swear word is indicative of *not* being a Christian.

Answer (score 2):

1. Religion was expressly forbidden in Battle School. **Card covered this topic extensively in many Enderverse short stories, most notably Dink-involved Sinterclaas one** (*A War of Gifts*).
2. Dink is Dutch. Netherlands were under Warsaw Pact (seen in Shadow series). As such, it's plausible that using religious references in everyday speech seemed out of character to Card (by 1991, very few people in USSR would have casually blasphemed that way - it fell out of habit). Since Shadow series came out in 2001+, it's hard to say if this idea would have been foremost in Card's mind in 1991 though, so this reason is less likely.

Comment: Ender's Game itself mentions that the Netherlands was part of the Second Warsaw Pact. *"In Dink's home in the Netherlands's, with three generations under Russian hegemony, perhaps it was all controlled, but Ender knew that lies could not last long in America."*

Comment: If you're back to answering, then can you please fix up your answer to address my comment? (btw, this was my first question I posted on SE)